# As the pop up open issue occuring on visibility of div tags code timely

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have `pop.jsp` in which there is two div tag when i click on `FindByid` then only find by id field show and if i click on `findByname` then that field show only which is perfectly working .But the problem is that when i open a pop sometimes none of the field visible  or sometime it smoothly works i don't  know why it's happen i want to visible the respective field on click of button accordingly

note sometimes visibility of div tag perfectly is working only on  `internet explorer` for other browsers no div tag is visible  so plz resolve my problem

here is my index.jsp pop code through which i mopenieng pop up

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function windowLoadByName(windowHeight, windowWidth) {
    var centerWidth = (window.screen.width - windowWidth) / 2;
    var centerHeight = (window.screen.height - windowHeight) / 2;

    newWindow = window.open(
            'PopUp.jsp',
            'mywindow',
            'resizable=0,width=' + windowWidth + ',height=' + windowHeight
                    + ',left=' + centerWidth + ',top=' + centerHeight,
            "status=1").divHiding(1);
    newWindow.focus();

}
function windowLoadById(windowHeight, windowWidth) {
    var centerWidth = (window.screen.width - windowWidth) / 2;
    var centerHeight = (window.screen.height - windowHeight) / 2;
    newWindow = window.open(
            'PopUp.jsp',
            'mywindow',
            'resizable=0,width=' + windowWidth + ',height=' + windowHeight
                    + ',left=' + centerWidth + ',top=' + centerHeight)
            .divHiding(2);

    newWindow.focus();
    return newWindow.name;
}
```

and this is my pop.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/input-1.0"
    prefix="input"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadByName() {
        var l = document.getElementById("firstName");
        var v = l.value;
        window.opener.loadName(v);
        window.close();
    }
    function loadById() {
        var ids = document.getElementById("id");
        var v = ids.value;
        window.opener.loadId(v);
        window.close();
    }

    function divHiding(id) {

        var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
        var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');


        // Check what the value of the button pressed and displays the correct div
        if (id == 1)
            div1.style.display = 'block';
        else if (id == 2) {
            div2.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="employeeForm" method="get">
        <div id="div1" style="display: none;">
            Employee Name:
            <center>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />
            </center>
            <center>
                <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search"
                    onclick="loadByName()" />
            </center>
        </div>
        <div id="div2" style="display: none;">
            Employee Id:
            <center>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="id" />
            </center>
            <center>
                <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search"
                    onclick="loadById()" />
            </center>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are invoking the divHiding function in the window.open(..), and the page might no be loaded when the function is invoked, this is the reason that sometimes it works and sometimes not.
The solution I suggest is to pass by url parameter the div you want to show:

```
newWindow = window.open(
            'PopUp.jsp?div=1',
            'mywindow',
            'resizable=0,width=' + windowWidth + ',height=' + windowHeight
                    + ',left=' + centerWidth + ',top=' + centerHeight)
```

In the popup.jsp you can do the below code to check if the parameter is 1 and then set the div1 to visible, and do the same for div2

```
<div id="div1" style="display: <%=(request.getParameter("div").equals("1") ? "block" : "none") %>;">
```